# Запрос SQL c NULL, 0 и 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Столбец `region` в таблице `db` может принимать значение NULL, 0  или 1.

Какой SQL спрос может вывести все результаты с NULL и 1?

Запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `db` WHERE `region` != '0'
```

не работает т.к. по логике NULL и 0 в данном случае как одно и то-же, как быть?

Comment: На NULL можно проверять только явно. так что `where table=1 OR table IS NULL`

Comment: спасибо, поробывал, но не работает. Причем как-то странно, вообще запрос не возвращается, даже с ошибкой

Comment: TABLE ключевое слово его нельзя так просто применять - попробуйте переименовать поле

Comment: Ну да, это я второпях написл да и обратные кавычки в комментах писать сложно. заключите table в них как у вас было. а ошибки скорее всего ваш клиент в отдельное окно выводит которого не видно

Comment: это я для примера, но поменял. Даже с кавычками не работает запрос

Comment: Всё работает превосходно: https://pastebin.com/fPiGJQTu Вы можете пояснить, что именно у Вас не получается?

Comment: where IfNull(`region`,1)!=0

Comment: @Zufir ваш вариант работает, спасибо! Если напишите отдельно отмечу как решение

Comment: @Zufir Угу, только зачем нужно сравнение? вполне достаточно просто `where IfNull(region,1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `db` WHERE IfNull(`region`,1)!=0
```